# Why my button element don't trigger the submitForm method?

Tags: 8, forms

I have a form with a `<button>` element

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['address'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#autocomplete_route_name' => 'geocoder_autocomplete.autocomplete',
      '#title' => '<span>' . t('Find an adoration place') . '</span>',
    );

    $form['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'inline_template',
      '#template' => '<button type="submit" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></button>',
    ];

    return $form;
  }
```

When I click the button the page is refreshed but the `submitForm()` method is not called. If I add an `<input type='button'>` element in the form and I click the `<button>` or the `<input type='button'>` the `submitForm()` is called.

```
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['address'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#autocomplete_route_name' => 'geocoder_autocomplete.autocomplete',
      '#title' => '<span>' . t('Find an adoration place') . '</span>',
    );

    $form['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'inline_template',
      '#template' => '<button type="submit" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></button>',
    ];

    $form['submit1'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
    ];

    return $form;
  }
```

I'm missing something here? Why my button element don't trigger the submitForm method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first "submit" button doesn't get recognized by Drupal as a button because you use an inline template.

If you want to add a class on your button use:

```
$form['submit'] = [
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
  '#attributes'=> ['class'=>['glyphicon', 'glyphicon-search']],
];
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, this is the answer for my question, but I really need a <button> element in my form because the client want a icon in the button and with the <input type='button'> you can't do it, any ideas?

Comment: Ofcourse you can. You can use the :after or :before selector in CSS...

Comment: Or set a background on the submit button via CSS

Comment: I'm not very skilled with css, can you share an example, please?

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=css3+%3Aafter+icon

Comment: we can't have a <button> element that submit the form?

Comment: No, Drupal expects a submit-type

Comment: I just found this: https://www.drupal.org/node/1671190 it seems that we need to wait until the 8.4

Comment: 8.4 won't have a stable release until the end of this year...